# openwhisk ansible setup.yml failed with error "ansible/_distribution is undefined"

Tags: openwhisk

I want to install *Openwhisk* with *docker* using *ansible*. But when I run

```
ansible-playbook -i environments/local setup.yml
```

I get this error:

```
> The conditional check 'nginx.ssl.cert == "openwhisk-server-cert.pem"'
failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (nginx.ssl.cert ==
"openwhisk-server-cert.pem"): 'ansible_distribution' is undefined  The error
appears to have been in '/home/parichehr/openwhisk/ansible/setup.yml': line 60,
column 5, but may be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax
problem.  The offending line appears to be:    # Generate nginx certificates   -
name: gen untrusted server certificate for host     ^ here
```

Comment: Check your ansible version. With `ansible 2.7.7` this is not reproducible. What version are you using?
`

Comment: I am using 2.5.2

Comment: I change my ansible version but I still get the same error and when I do like the answer below, this problem is solved but in TASK [gen untrusted server certificate for host], the error becomes much more: non-zero return code
generating server certificate request generating self-signed password-less
server certificate
140117883516224:error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start
line:../crypto/pem/pem_lib.c:745:Expecting: CERTIFICATE REQUEST

Answer (score 2):

`ansible_distribution` is a variable defined through the task `Gathering Facts`. Gather facts is enable by default but if you want to be sure you are gathering facts you can wirte `gather_facts: yes` in your playbook as below

```
- name: Setup.yml
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: yes

  tasks:
  ...........
```

Comment: I do like this and  the problem is solved but in TASK [gen untrusted server certificate for host], the error becomes much more: non-zero return code generating server certificate request generating self-signed password-less server certificate 140117883516224:error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line:../crypto/pem/pem_lib.c:745:Expecting: CERTIFICATE REQUEST